# Inserting javascript global variable in <div> tag in HTML body

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following tag in HTML:

```
<div data-dojo-type="dojox.data.XmlStore" 
     data-dojo-props="url:'http://135.250.70.162:8081/eqmWS/services/eq/Equipment/All/6204/2', label:'text'" 
     data-dojo-id="bookStore3"></div>
```

I have the values 6204 and 2 in a couple of global variables in the script section:

```
<html>
  <head>
     <script>
      ...
      var newNeId = gup('neId');
      var newNeGroupId = gup('neGroupId');
      ...
     </script>
  </head>
</html>
```

Is it possible to have these variables in the div tag in the HTML body?  If so, how?

To clarify this a bit more, I need to have the URL in the  tag something like this:

```
url: 'http://135.250.70.162:8081/eqmWS/services/eq/Equipment/All/'+newNeGroupId+'/'+newNeId
```

Comment: @EricFortis These values come from the URL and I parse the URL and store these values in a variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed it according to your requirement:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            // example data
            var newNeId = 10;
            var newNeGroupId = 500;
            window.onload = function(e){
                var myDiv = document.getElementById("myDiv");
                myDiv.setAttribute("data-dojo-props", "url:'http://135.250.70.162:8081/eqmWS/services/eq/Equipment/All/" + newNeId + "/" + newNeGroupId + "', label:'text'");
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="myDiv" data-dojo-type="dojox.data.XmlStore" 
     data-dojo-props="url:'http://135.250.70.162:8081/eqmWS/services/eq/Equipment/All/6204/2', label:'text'" 
     data-dojo-id="bookStore3"></div>
    </body>
</html>​
```

Comment: Not exactly.  The values newNeId and newNeGroupId should be substituted in place of 6204 and 2 in the url: http://135.250.70.162:8081/eqmWS/services/eq/Equipment/All/6204/2

Comment: @RazvanPanda Will try and let you know. Thanks.

Comment: @RazvanPanda: just one question... what will happen to data-dojo-props assignment in <div ... data-dojo-props="...">?

Comment: @Shree: It will be replaced with `"url:'http://135.250.70.162:8081/eqmWS/services/eq/Equipment/All/" + newNeId + "/" + newNeGroupId + "', label:'text'"`. You can inspect the DOM in your browser to see the changes.

Comment: @RazvanPanda: doesn't get replaced :(

Comment: @Shree: If you use the code exactly as it is in my answer it works. Are you doing anything different?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12522/discussion-between-shree-and-rzvan-panda)

Answer (score 1):

You could add them to the `<div>` using the same datalist pattern ([MDN docu](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.dataset)) as Dojo:

```
<div id="savebox" data-newNeId="6204" data-newNeGroupId="2"></div>
```

These attributes are then accessible by the `element.dataset.itemName`.

```
var div = document.querySelector( '#savebox' );
// access
console.log( div.dataset.newNeId );
console.log( div.dataset.newNeGroupId );
```

As @EricFortis pointed out, the question remains, why you want to do this. This only makes sense, if you pass those values on from the server side.

Comment: These values are not known.  I get these values in the URL as parameters and I parse it and retrieve the values in javascript.

Comment: @Shree So why do you want them to be stored in that div? Why not just create some namespace in `window` and store them there?

Comment: I need these values in a few other script functions too.

Comment: @Shree All JavaScript functions on a page have access to the `window` object and thus to your values.

Answer (score 1):

Take one parent div then set its id and then you can rewrite whole div tag with attributes using `innerHTML`.

```
document.getElementById('id of parent div').innerHTml="<div data-dojo-type=/"dojox.data.XmlStore/" 
 data-dojo-props=/"url:'http://135.250.70.162:8081/eqmWS/services/eq/Equipment/All/6204/2', label:'text'/" 
 data-dojo-id=/"bookStore3/"></div>";
```

you can append values you wants in `innerhtml` now.

Comment: Can you please be a bit more elaborate as I'm not very familiar with javascript or html?

Answer (score 0):

here's simple native js code to do it

```
var body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
var myDiv = document.createElement('div');
myDiv.setAttribute('id', 'myDiv');
var text = 'newNeId: ' + newNeId + 
'<br/> newNeGroupId: ' + newNeGroupId';
body.appendChild(myDiv);
document.getElementById('myDiv').innerHTML = text;
```